# How to use dispose() properly?

Tags: java, libgdx, destructor, dispose

For example, if I have an instance of an object, which implements Disposable, let's say it is

```
BitmapFont someFont = new BitmapFont();
```

According to LibGDX documentation, I should call the dispose() method as soon as the object is no longer needed. But what if decide to assign new font to the same variable:

```
someFont = new BitmapFont();
```

Should I first call dispose() before such an assignment in order to prevent a memory leak? In other words, which variant is correct, this

```
    BitmapFont someFont = new BitmapFont();
    //do something
    someFont.dispose();
    someFont = new BitmapFont();
    //do something else
    someFont.dispose();
```

or this:

```
    BitmapFont someFont = new BitmapFont();
    //do something
    someFont = new BitmapFont();
    //do something else
    someFont.dispose();
```

I'm currently thinking that the first one is correct, and it seemes that dispose() behaves just like the destructor in C++, except for the fact that it is not called automatically.

So, which version is actually correct?

Comment: Note that you should not create new fonts "on the fly", as this is rather slow. Try to create them when your app is created and keep them until your app is closed completely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your variable is simply a pointer to a given object, not an overarching container that holds all references that it has ever encompassed.  If you were to follow your second code example, you are only calling dispose on the second BitmapFont instance, not the first one.  Your first pattern is technically correct, and you would want to consider try/finally blocks as well to ensure dispose is called when you are done with it.

Answer (score -2):

Go with your second example, the first example is also correct but the the call to the first dispose() is redundant since you are using the same pointer again. 
Good luck :)

**Update :**

Sorry ! I checked I was wrong :/ You need to call the first **dispose()** function in order to avoid memory leaking **so the correct example is the first one**

Comment: But then the first font is never disposed at all and causes a memory leak.

Comment: @minos23, are you sure? :)

Comment: my idea was based on a reflection that how can be leaking of memory if the dispose() method is called anyway and if we take a look at the dispose () method we could see that all the textures will be disposes

Comment: @minos23, if we have two objects located in memory, and only one pointer to one object, how can we access the second object if we just call one's dispose() ?

Comment: This answer is wrong. The first object will be leaked.